# How do libgdx camera and viewport work?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, viewport

Following is my code,

```
public class ViewPortTestScreen1 extends MScreen {

    private Viewport viewport;
    private Stage stage;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    public ViewPortTestScreen1() {
        // camera
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        // viewport
        // viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);
        viewport = new FitViewport(1000, 1000, camera);
        // stage
        stage = new Stage(viewport);
        // actor
        Texture texture = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        TextureActor textureActor = new TextureActor(0, 0, texture);
        TextureActor textureActor2 = new TextureActor(viewport.getWorldWidth() - texture.getWidth(), 0, texture);
        TextureActor textureActor3 = new TextureActor(0,viewport.getWorldHeight() - texture.getHeight(), texture);
        TextureActor textureActor4 = new TextureActor(viewport.getWorldWidth() - texture.getWidth(), viewport.getWorldHeight() - texture.getHeight(), texture);
        stage.addActor(textureActor);
        stage.addActor(textureActor2);
        stage.addActor(textureActor3);
        stage.addActor(textureActor4);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);
        // stage
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height,true);
    }

    private class TextureActor extends Actor {

        private Texture texture;
        private float x;
        private float y;

        TextureActor(float x, float y, Texture texture) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.texture = texture;
            setWidth(this.texture.getWidth());
            setHeight(this.texture.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        public void act(float delta) {
            super.act(delta);
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
            batch.draw(texture, x, y, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

When I set viewport width and height with Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and getHeight(), it display in full screen and the images are large as shown in the following screen shot,

[image]

when I set viewport width and height with some arbitrary values, it does not show in full screen and the size of images also changed. Here is the screen shot,

[image]

The problem with me is why the size of the images change and how the viewport's world width and height values (units) work? LibGDX wiki say they are not pixel.
I'm testing with android studio and emulator,
7"  WSVGA (Tablet)
API 28
1024x600
mdpi